# Zend2: Set currency format to have a space for the thousand seperator?

Tags: zend-framework2, currency-formatting

When setting the pattern for the [currencyFormatter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.setpattern.php), you can use:

```
#,##0.###
```

To get:

```
1,0000.00
```

But I want to get:

```
1 0000.00
```

How do I alter the format string to get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the use of 'symbol' attribute to overwrite your own curreny.

```
echo Zend_Currency->toCurrency(
    4000,
    array(
        'currency' => "USD",
        'symbol' => ''
    )
);
```

Comment: I tired using locale like that and I end up getting 1,000.00, which is wrong for my country. It must be 1 000.00.